Is expansion necessary for negative heat capacity?
Gravitationally bound gas has negative heat capacity. It expands and its temperature decreases as heat is added.
What about electromagnetically bound systems such as solid materials? Is it possible to see the same effect in a material without necessarily changing its size, perhaps only its microscopic properties, structure and electronic degrees of freedom? After all, there is some space inside every crystal lattice, and molecules or electron orbitals may expand inside this space.

Heat capacity is always positive.  At constant volume, it is equal to the partial derivative of the internal energy with respect to temperature, and at constant pressure, it is equal to the partial derivative of enthalpy with respect to temperature.  Both definitions are equilibrium properties of the material, and not the process.

What word(s) is used to describe the ability of a system to lower its temperature in response to the addition of heat? Is this title mistaken or is it talking about the process of adding heat? https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001PhRvL..86.1191S/abstract

Negative heat capacity can occur in non-additive systems, i.e., ones where the energy of a system which is made up of several subsystems does not equal the sum of the energies of the subsystems. Non-additivity can occur in systems with long range interactions, where the interaction energy between subsystems scales with the volume rather than the surface area. They can also occur in small systems, where the volume is not much larger than the surface area.
Gravity is indeed a long-ranged interaction, and thus astrophysics provides prime examples for negative heat capacity. But negative heat capacity has been observed in other systems as well, such as 2-dimensional turbulence and free electron lasers. It has also been analyzed theoretically in toy models such as long-range interacting Ising models. Such systems and models need not even have a notion of volume, and thus negative heat capacity in these systems will not be related to expansion.
For reviews on systems with long range interactions and their statistical physics (which include references to physical systems exhibiting negative specific heat) see:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1457
https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0323
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/31/1/003

